# Setting CSS styles, color, for MathJax

Tags: css, colors, mathjax

Hi I am trying to add styles to my MathJax output. In particular I would like to set a global color for my equations (so that it matches the styles on the rest of my page). Currently I have the following configuration.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
      tex2jax: {
        inlineMath: [ ['$', '$'] ],
        displayMath: [ ['$$', '$$']],
        processEscapes: true,
        skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre', 'code']
      },
      messageStyle: "none",
      "HTML-CSS": { 
          preferredFont: "TeX", 
          availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], 
          styles: {".MathJax" {color: "#CCCCCC";}} 
          }
    });
</script>
<script src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However if I include the `styles` tag in my configuration the math on my page just refuses to display at all. On the other hand if I remove it, it displays fine.

Edit: I should also note that I have tried adding the styles directly to my CSS as suggested in other questions but this resulted in the same thing, no math being displayed at all.

---

*UPDATE:* I have added the : as Davide suggests below, now my equations display but the styling information is ignored. The styling seems to be inherited from the body of the page but wrapping the math in a div with different styling doesn't seem to affect it either.

*UPDATE2:* I have solved my the issue of the mathjax ignoring style commands. The color for text was globally set by a line in my CSS * { colour: #292929 }. This meant that the style from MathJax was being ignored. Simply changing * to body, a, p, h1, h2 fixed the issue.

Comment: Argh. You should never edit your question in such a way that existing answers get invalidated. I revert your edits; this is not a forum but strictly a Question/Answer site. If your questions is answered, it is done.

Comment: Thanks for the comment - I take your point about editing the code. I think it would be beneficial to leave the comments I made at the end, as that is what ultimately solved the issue (even though I asked the wrong question), but you clearly feel strongly about the issue so I'll leave it.

Comment: I must admit I took the path of least resistance to make this "correct" again. I will add your comments again :)

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the colon after `".MathJax"`.  Your code should be

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
  tex2jax: {
    inlineMath: [ ['$', '$'] ],
    displayMath: [ ['$$', '$$']],
    processEscapes: true,
    skipTags: ['script', 'noscript', 'style', 'textarea', 'pre', 'code']
  },
  messageStyle: "none",
  "HTML-CSS": { 
      preferredFont: "TeX", 
      availableFonts: ["STIX","TeX"], 
      styles: {".MathJax": {color: "#CCCCCC"}} 
      }
});
</script>
```

and then it should work for you.

Comment: Ah! that was stupid. It is displaying now, however it is still ignoring the styling information. I have updated my question. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You could also have done it by using `".MathJax": {color: "#CCCCCC ! important"}` to override the CSS on `*`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

For MathJax 3.x, use:

```css
.MJX-TEX{
    color: red !important;
}
```