# MathJax equations are colored in jekyll

Tags: css, jekyll, mathjax

My MathJax equations on my Jekyll blog are green. I think the CSS in the Alembic theme is overriding the ability of MathJax equations to inherit the same color as the text in the blog post.

I have tried the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21580476/setting-css-styles-color-for-mathjax) using the color red to test it:

Namely, adding to `_layout/post.html`:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": { 
      styles: {".MathJax": {color: "#FF0000 ! important"}} 
      }
});
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This doesn't work. And, oddly, when I type $$n=7$ the `n=` part is green and the `7` is red. Very odd.

My theme, a fork of the Alembic theme, is [here](https://github.com/SimonEnsemble/SimonEnsemble.github.io). I am wondering how I can modify a CSS file to enable MathJax to inherit the font color in my blog post.

[Here](https://simonensemble.github.io/statistical%20mechanics/2017/10/06/freelyjointedchain/) is a live example.

Comment: You might want to share a live example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I added a live example at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to clashing class names. From a quick look, the problems come down to `.mi` and `.mo`  which the the syntax highlighter sets ([these lines](https://github.com/SimonEnsemble/SimonEnsemble.github.io/blob/7faf7f51c609c80d45ae4eb961536bc3b4f83590/_sass/_syntax.scss#L44-L45)) but MathJax also uses in its HTML-CSS output.

You can work around this by, e.g., removing the styles from `_syntax.scss` highlighter (or scoping them to a wrapper class if available).

From the MathJax end, you could workaround this by adding

```
.MathJax .mi, .MathJax .mo {
    color: inherit;
}
```

to your CSS.

A simpler alternative might be to use another MathJax output, e.g., the CommonHTML output.